# What can be said about the expected exponential of $X$ given $\mathsf EX$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-function, expected-value

If I have a continuous random variable $X$ and I know the expected value $\mathsf E X$, is there any way to derive the expected value $\mathsf E \exp(X)$ outside of using the moment generating function or the PDF of $X$?

Comment: you dont need the moment generating function. It is well-known that $\operatorname{E}[g(X)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(t)\mathop{}\!d F_X(t)$ for any measurable function $g$. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)

Comment: @Masacroso Indeed, but what if the PDF/CDF of X is unknown?

Comment: Literally the only guarantee that you can make is $E[e^X] \geq e^{E[X]}$; anything between that and $+\infty$ can be attained by a suitable distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can say $Ee^{X} \geq e^{EX}$ but the exact value of $Ee^{X}$ cannot be determined. Example: Suppose $X=0$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$. Then $EX=0$ and $EY=0$. But $Ee^{X}=1$ and $Ee^{Y}=\sqrt e$. This show that  $Ee^{X}$ cannot be determined from $EX$ alone.

Comment: Thank you, your example cleared up my confusion!

Comment: Kavi, you know about the EoQS.  Please review it in full, because you just violated the policy again. [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the existence of the moment generating function, $M_X(t)=\mathsf Ee^{tX}$, all the expected value tells you is its first derivtaive at $t=0$:
$$
\mathsf E X=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}M_X(t)\bigg|_{t=0}.
$$
So you can derive $\mathsf EX$ from $\mathsf Ee^{tX}$ but the converse is not true. Without knowing the density or distribution functions of $X$, there is no way to evaluate $\mathsf E e^{tX}$ for any $t$, by just knowing $\mathsf E X$.

Comment: Please review *carefully* the current policy of [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1), which now applies to not only askers, but also the answerers that answer very low quality questions.

Comment: @amWhy I believe (could be wrong) that this answer came before the quality standards began being enforced. I seem to have this comment pasted below a few of my answers but continue to watch high rep. users doing the same thing without warning.

Comment: It was posted, the EoQS, on May 6th, 2001, a full month before you answered here.  I meant only to notify you, in case you hadn't been aware.   I did not flag or downvote.  And yes, some high rep users continue, none the less to violate the policy, but some have been suspended, and we are watching them carefully. Feel free to flag any such answer you encounter.

Comment: @amWhy OK. Thank you for the explanation.